# Create a Native token for voting & burn afterwards

Tags: native-assets, token, burn

I am looking to issue voting Tokens.
The basic idea is that I will send something like 100 tokens to 10 people. Then there will be three wallets that act as ballot box.

In order to incentivise the people to vote within a certain timeframe I wan’t to burn the tokens after a certain period of time.

Am I right that I can do so by burning the tokens as token issuer?
And when burning, what will happen to the ADA used during token minting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there might be better ways to build a voting system than to use native assets as "votes" in the future when we have smart contracts on Cardano. But of course your proposal would be possible.

Once the tokens have left your wallet, you won't be able to burn them. That can only be done by the owners of the tokens. There is this question where you can find more info on how token burning works: [What does it mean to "burn" a token?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/q/1941/1142)

The ADA used to mint the tokens is used to "pay" for the minting process. This has nothing to do with the burning of tokens.

Comment: OK thnx. 
I am aware that this way of voting is suboptimal, but I'am looking for a voting mechanism which works prior to smart contracts release.